# cant access vector object's function through -> operator

Tags: c++, pointers, vector, operator-keyword

This is a basic binary search function for a vector.I want to access an object's get function but i get error.

```
bool binFindInVec(vector<Client> *vec,string sur){


    int from,to,pos;

    from = 0;
    to = vec->size()-1;


    while(from<=to){

        pos = (from+to)/2;
        if(vec[pos]->getSurname() == sur){
            return true;
        }
        else if(vec[pos]->getSurname() > sur){
            to = pos-1;
        }
        else{
            from = pos + 1;
        }
    }
    return NULL;    
}
```

the error:

> In function 'bool binFindInVec(std::vector*, std::string)':
>      176    14  [Error] base operand of '->' has non-pointer type 'std::vector'
>      179    19  [Error] base operand of '->' has non-pointer type 'std::vector'

Comment: You might want `(*vec)[pos].getSurname()`.

Comment: Also, you could make things less complicated by passing a reference instead: `bool binFindInVec(vector<Client>& vec, string sur){`. Then you can just use: `vec[pos].getSurname()`.

Comment: You might also want to think about why you need to pass a pointer to your vector rather than a reference.

Comment: Since `vec` is a `vector<Client> *`, `vec[x]` (a.k.a. `*(vec + x)`) is a `vector<Client>`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should dereference 'vec' before calling its operator[]:

```
(*vec)[pos].getSurname();
```

Better yet (and much safer), pass the vector parameter by reference. NOT as pointer:

```
bool binFindInVec(vector<Client> const& vec,string sur)
```

Comment: Also pass by `const&` if you are not actually manipulating the vector.

Comment: thanks i used const& because i don't actually manipulate the vector

Answer (score -1):

Writing `vec[pos]->getSurname()` assumes the elements of `vec` are pointers (or smart pointers). Since you pass a vector of plain `Client` objects as pointer, you need to dereference `vec` to be able to use `operator[]`

Comment: Not sure why this was down voted.  This looks correct.  Not sure what you mean by *you need to dereference it as pointed by roalz.* though

Comment: i meant you need to write this `(*vec)` to be able to use `operator[]`

Comment: You might want to edit that into the answer then to improve it.